# Как отправить сообщение WhatsApp с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, whatsapp

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как отправить сообщение через WhatsApp с помощью PHP?

CHAT-API не актуален: он уже не поддерживается и не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Получить доступ к не публичному api или купить услугу у агрегаторов (например https://prostor-sms.ru/services/whatsapp-sending/  или https://smsaero.ru/whatsapp/ или любой другой)

Comment: У агрегатов не вариант они не предоставляют какого то постоянного номера. Дык вот кто бы дал доступ к не публичному API)

Comment: whatapp может только дать. Но надо быть крутым перцем (например большим банком) и ничего не слать хоть мало напоминающее спам.

Comment: Так если бы спамил. Тем кому мне нужно они сами требует уведомления на Whatsapp, жалко что конечно Whatsapp идёт не потому пути.

Comment: Пробовал в свое время. [Есть питоновские либы](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup), которые можно дернуть с PHP. Но дело в другом: лицокнига ведет войну против таких. Берите агрегатор, он решит проблему на коммерческой основе. Или используйте альтернативные мессенжеры.

Comment: Есть вариант открыть веб-версию и через JS слать сообщения. Набор: веб-драйвер + JS + браузер. Я пытался сделать, но забил.